# Paste multiple elements of a list of vectors

Tags: r, list, data.table, paste

I have a data table like this

```
        ID           Name
1: 2760925   01_HOOFD_010
2: 2760925   01_HOOFD_015
3: 2771451   01_HOOFD_010
4: 2771451 01_HOOFD_190_2
5: 2771451 01_HOOFD_030_2
6: 2771451 08_AWB45_020_2
7: 2771451   08_AWB45_040
8: 2771451 01_HOOFD_065_2
```

For the "Name" field, I want to have the part after the second underscore in a separate data.table column.
Currently, I use strplit with the "_" as the token, but my problem is that some records have 3 elements, and some others 4.
My current solution is

```
DT$code_3<-DT[,.(lapply(strsplit(Name,"_"),"[",3:4)),][,.(lapply(V1,function(x) paste(na.omit(x),collapse="_"))),]
```

but I doubt if this is the most fact / concise way...
Do you have any better ideas?
Thank you

```
> dput(DT)
structure(list(ID = c(2760925L, 2760925L, 2771451L, 2771451L, 
2771451L, 2771451L, 2771451L, 2771451L), Name = c("01_HOOFD_010", 
"01_HOOFD_015", "01_HOOFD_010", "01_HOOFD_190_2", "01_HOOFD_030_2", 
"08_AWB45_020_2", "08_AWB45_040", "01_HOOFD_065_2")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Name"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103819178>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <-structure(list(ID = c(2760925L, 2760925L, 2771451L, 2771451L, 
2771451L, 2771451L, 2771451L, 2771451L), Name = c("01_HOOFD_010", 
"01_HOOFD_015", "01_HOOFD_010", "01_HOOFD_190_2", "01_HOOFD_030_2", 
"08_AWB45_020_2", "08_AWB45_040", "01_HOOFD_065_2")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Name"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))

x$two <- gsub( "(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)" , "" , x$Name )
```

Comment: Another version is `sub('([^_]+_){2}', '', x$Name)` or the `data.table` syntax would be `x[, two:= sub('([^_]+_){2}', '', Name)]`